# Visual Studio 2022 - Pressing tab cycles through windows instead of indenting

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I've somehow changes a setting where pressing the tab key moves the focus around the different section of my Visual Studio editor, instead of adding space within my text editor.

How do I undo this?

I've heard this described as "tab trapping" and "tab moves focus" in VS Code, but I'm struggling to find an answer for Visual Studio 2022.

Edit: I can fix it by closing an re-opening Visual Studio, but it's annoying not knowing how I did it.

Comment: Maybe your CTRL key is stuck ? try pressing it once, release it, then press TAB and see if it changes the behavior